# Python, pandas iteration from school to student by distance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I'm on a scholar map project. The objective here is to send students to the nearest school possible. But we have really limited place so we need to deal with it. I will mention here the conditions that I want, the data as an example,the desired result, the code that I have put in place which only works partially and the result which is also partial.

We have a table of students who have an id, a table of schools who have an id and a place limit and finally a table that calculates the distance for each student to each school with distance information.

Conditions :

I want every student to go to the school closest to them. If it is possible because there are places available, you must then add +1 in the school table so that it does not exceed the available places and link the student to the school in the student table. If a school has no more places, then the student in question will go to the second school closest to him, always checking the place parameters etc...

Data :

Here is a simple example of the data:

```
df_eleves = pd.DataFrame({
    'id_eleve' : [
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
    ]
})

df_ecoles = pd.DataFrame({
    'id_ecole' : [
    1,2,3,4,5
    ],
    'places' : [
    2,4,3,1,2
    ]
})

df_distance = pd.DataFrame({
    'id_eleve' : [
    1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,
    5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9
    ],
    'id_ecole' : [
    1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,
    1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5
    ],
    'distance' : [
    20,30,15,9,8,55,100,73,42,4,15,88,32,3,25,
    75,69,78,20,10,56,21,74,56,12,19,5,35,45,82,
    13,75,63,14,9,1,14,98,20,6,48,65,32,147,65
    ]
})
```

The desired result:

df_eleves:

| id_eleve | id_ecole | distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 8 |
| 2 | 5 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |

df_ecoles:

| id_ecole | places | student |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

The code :

Here's the code I've made so far and it's not working very well

```
import pandas as pd

df_eleves = pd.DataFrame({
    'id_eleve' : [
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
    ]
})

df_ecoles = pd.DataFrame({
    'id_ecole' : [
    1,2,3,4,5
    ],
    'places' : [
    2,4,3,1,2
    ]
})

df_distance = pd.DataFrame({
    'id_eleve' : [
    1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,
    5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9
    ],
    'id_ecole' : [
    1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,
    1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5
    ],
    'distance' : [
    20,30,15,9,8,55,100,73,42,4,15,88,32,3,25,
    75,69,78,20,10,56,21,74,56,12,19,5,35,45,82,
    13,75,63,14,9,1,14,98,20,6,48,65,32,147,65
    ]
})


# Sorting distances for each student in ascending order
df_distance_sorted = df_distance.sort_values(['id_eleve', 'distance'])

# Initialisation des colonnes à None dans le dataframe df_eleves
df_eleves['id_ecole'] = None
df_eleves['distance'] = None

# Loop on students
for index, row in df_eleves.iterrows():
    
    # Retrieve student ID
    id_eleve = row['id_eleve']
    
    # Filtering the df distance dataframe to keep only unassigned schools
    df_distance_filtered = df_distance_sorted[(df_distance_sorted['id_eleve'] == id_eleve) &
                                               (~df_distance_sorted['id_ecole'].isin(df_eleves['id_ecole']))]
    

    # Loop over schools sorted by increasing distance to assign student to nearest available school
    for index2, row2 in df_distance_filtered.iterrows():
        
        id_ecole = row2['id_ecole']
        
        # Si l'école est disponible, on attribue l'élève et on met à jour le nombre de places disponibles
        if df_ecoles.loc[df_ecoles['id_ecole'] == id_ecole, 'places'].iloc[0] > 0:
            df_eleves.at[index, 'id_ecole'] = id_ecole
            df_eleves.at[index, 'distance'] = row2['distance']
            df_ecoles.loc[df_ecoles['id_ecole'] == id_ecole, 'places'] -= 1
            break


# Result display
print(df_eleves)
```

Here is the result:

| id_eleve | id_ecole | distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 8 |
| 2 | 4 | 42 |
| 3 | 1 | 15 |
| 4 | 2 | 69 |
| 5 | 3 | 74 |
| 6 | None | None |
| 7 | None | None |
| 8 | None | None |
| 9 | None | None |

It doesn't work very well. I therefore appeal to your knowledge to help me if possible. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the unique schools and students values. I have sorted the df by distance as a heuristic to get the minumum distance (but this could also be an optimization problem and so require other technique to solve this, e.g., linear optimization)

Using the data you provided, I have first merged to consolidate all in a single df.

```py
data = df_distance.merge(df_ecoles, on='id_ecole').sort_values('distance')

# Preparing the dictionaries to then build the dataframes as the excpected result you presented
schools_students = {student:{'ecole_id':'', 'distance':0} for student in data['id_eleve'].unique()}
school_places = {school:{'places': df_ecoles.loc[df_ecoles['id_ecole']==school]['places'].values[0] , 'students':0} for school in df_ecoles['id_ecole'] }

# iterate through each unique student and school in the df
for student in data['id_eleve'].unique():
    for school in data['id_ecole'].unique():
        distance = data.loc[ (data['id_eleve']==student) & (data['id_ecole']==school) ]['distance'].values[0]
        # Check if a school still has availability
        if school_places[school]['students'] < school_places[school]['places']:
            schools_students[student]['ecole_id'] = school
            schools_students[student]['distance'] = distance
            school_places[school]['students'] += 1
            break

df_eleve_new = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(schools_students, orient='index').reset_index().rename({'index':'eleve_id'}, axis=1)

df_ecole_new = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(school_places, orient='index').reset_index().rename({'index':'ecole_id'}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df_eleve_new
   eleve_id  ecole_id  distance
0         8         1         1
1         3         1        15
2         2         4        42
3         6         5        82
4         1         5         8
5         7         2        75
6         4         2        69
7         5         2        21
8         9         2        65


>>> df_ecole_new
   ecole_id  places  students
0         1       2         2
1         2       4         4
2         3       3         0
3         4       1         1
4         5       2         2
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read this right, given your dataset:

```py
df_distance = pd.DataFrame({
    'id_eleve' : [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9],
    'id_ecole' : [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5],
    'distance' : [20,30,15,9,8,55,100,73,42,4,15,88,32,3,25,75,69,78,20,10,56,21,74,56,12,19,5,35,45,82,13,75,63,14,9,1,14,98,20,6,48,65,32,147,65]
})
```

I think the result you seek might be obtained via `groupby()` and `idxmin()` via:

```py
closest = df_distance.loc[df_distance.groupby('id_eleve')["distance"].idxmin()].reset_index(drop=True)
print(closest)
```

giving:

|  | id_eleve | id_ecole | distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5 | 8 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 10 |
| 4 | 5 | 5 | 12 |
| 5 | 6 | 2 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 5 | 9 |
| 7 | 8 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 9 | 3 | 32 |

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, here is my code.

I first sort df_distance by "distance" and schools.
Then distribute school to students based on school places.
Then remove students who have been distributed a school.
If all the students have been distributed a school, but some schools are never distributed. restore df_distance, then distribute the rest school to students.

```
# sort distances by distance and student
df_distance.sort_values(['distance', 'id_ecole'], inplace=True)
df_distance_backup = df_distance

assigned_schools = pd.DataFrame()

# find nearest school place
for i in range(len(df_ecoles)):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    if df_distance.empty:
        df_distance = df_distance_backup
    else:
        df = df_distance[df_distance["id_ecole"] == df_ecoles.loc[i, "id_ecole"]].reset_index(drop=True)
        df = df.loc[list(range(df_ecoles.loc[i, "places"]))]
        assigned_schools = pd.concat([assigned_schools, df])
        for index, eleve in df["id_eleve"].iteritems():
            df_distance = df_distance[df_distance["id_eleve"] != eleve]

assigned_schools.sort_values(['id_eleve', "distance"], inplace=True)
assigned_schools.drop_duplicates(subset='id_eleve', inplace=True)
print(assigned_schools)
```

Output:

```
   id_eleve  id_ecole  distance
2         1         2        30
0         2         5         4
0         3         3        32
2         4         3        78
1         5         2        21
0         6         2         5
1         7         1        13
0         8         1         1
3         9         2        65
```